# Create Procedure to remove new lines in MySQL

Tags: mysql, newline, procedure

Hy everyboy.

I created a procedure to create sentences to remove the character `\n` in the columns of all tables from a database.

When I call the procedure introducing a database, it runs, but it doesn't indicate the `\n` (in fact, it gives you the newline and I don't like the newline)

The code is this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `p_corregir_saltos_de_linea_mysql` (IN v_bbdd VARCHAR(800))

BEGIN

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE `',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME, '` SET `',COLUMN_NAME,'` = REPLACE(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`,''\n'','''');')

FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`

WHERE `TABLE_NAME` IN (SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE')

AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = v_bbdd

AND `COLUMN_TYPE` LIKE 'varchar%';

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

What do I have to change in the procedure?

Comment: `REPLACE(\`',COLUMN_NAME,'\`,''\n'','''');`  This looks wrong; shouldn't it be `REPLACE(\`',COLUMN_NAME,'\`,'\n','');` ?

Comment: I tried this and it shows me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure merely returns SQL code like this:

```
UPDATE `database_name`.`table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'
','');
```

It's up to you to run the code afterwards. However, depending on how you run it you might find that your tool replaces your raw Unix line feeds with its default line feeds. It'd be more robust to generate escape sequences. For that, you need an extra layer of backslashes:

```
SELECT CONCAT(…'` SET `',COLUMN_NAME,'` = REPLACE(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`,''\\n'','''');')
                                                                   -- ^ One more
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Alvaro, this is the problem I had. I didn't add the second \.